# Rest API in PHP: {'error': "Missing 'inputs' or 'instances' key"}

Tags: php, api, rest, ubuntu, curl

For this function in **UBUNTU Terminal** which works well for my dockerized container (made using Tensorflow Serving):

```
curl -d '{"instances": [[ 1.18730158, -0.70909592,  1.21082918, -0.15897608, -0.87693017],
       [-0.3015204 , -0.44457891,  0.67090776,  1.1188499 , -0.87693017],
       [-0.52579254, -0.05989349,  0.40094705,  1.62998029,  1.13982729],
       [ 0.13322252,  0.58198159, -0.94885648,  1.1188499 , -0.87693017],
       [ 0.77441082, -0.68638116, -0.13897436,  0.35215431,  1.13982729],
       [ 0.69102759,  1.49057189, -0.13897436, -0.67010647,  1.13982729],
       [-0.25436574, -0.58819479,  0.13098635, -0.15897608,  1.13982729],
       [ 1.54671206,  2.58088026,  2.0207113 , -1.56458465,  1.13982729],
       [-0.97261165, -0.6292279 ,  0.40094705, -1.56458465, -0.87693017],
       [-0.36190136,  0.14893573,  0.40094705,  0.09658912,  1.13982729]]}'     -X POST http://localhost:8501/v1/models/model:predict
```

I have created a curl function in **PHP**:

```
    <?php 
        $endpoint = "http://localhost:8501/v1/models/model:predict";
$inputData = array(
    "instances" => 
       [[ 1.18730158, -0.70909592,  1.21082918, -0.15897608, -0.87693017],
       [-0.3015204 , -0.44457891,  0.67090776,  1.1188499 , -0.87693017],
       [-0.52579254, -0.05989349,  0.40094705,  1.62998029,  1.13982729],
       [ 0.13322252,  0.58198159, -0.94885648,  1.1188499 , -0.87693017],
       [ 0.77441082, -0.68638116, -0.13897436,  0.35215431,  1.13982729],
       [ 0.69102759,  1.49057189, -0.13897436, -0.67010647,  1.13982729],
       [-0.25436574, -0.58819479,  0.13098635, -0.15897608,  1.13982729],
       [ 1.54671206,  2.58088026,  2.0207113 , -1.56458465,  1.13982729],
       [-0.97261165, -0.6292279 ,  0.40094705, -1.56458465, -0.87693017],
       [-0.36190136,  0.14893573,  0.40094705,  0.09658912,  1.13982729]]
)
        
        $jsonData = array(
        "data" => $inputData,
        );
        $ch = 
        
        curl_init($endpoint);
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-Type: application/json"
        ),
        
        
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($jsonData)
        ));
        
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        ?>
```

But I keep getting the error:

```
{'error': "Missing 'inputs' or 'instances' key"}
```

I am sure I am not giving **the inputs correctly** but I do not know where to make the change. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are passing extra `"data" => $inputData` key inside your `$jsonData`. Try this way without **data**,

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:8501/v1/models/model:predict');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"instances\": [[ 1.18730158, -0.70909592,  1.21082918, -0.15897608, -0.87693017],\n       [-0.3015204 , -0.44457891,  0.67090776,  1.1188499 , -0.87693017],\n       [-0.52579254, -0.05989349,  0.40094705,  1.62998029,  1.13982729],\n       [ 0.13322252,  0.58198159, -0.94885648,  1.1188499 , -0.87693017],\n       [ 0.77441082, -0.68638116, -0.13897436,  0.35215431,  1.13982729],\n       [ 0.69102759,  1.49057189, -0.13897436, -0.67010647,  1.13982729],\n       [-0.25436574, -0.58819479,  0.13098635, -0.15897608,  1.13982729],\n       [ 1.54671206,  2.58088026,  2.0207113 , -1.56458465,  1.13982729],\n       [-0.97261165, -0.6292279 ,  0.40094705, -1.56458465, -0.87693017],\n       [-0.36190136,  0.14893573,  0.40094705,  0.09658912,  1.13982729]]}");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

**EDIT**: You can pass directly the `$inputData` like below

where

```
$inputData = [
    "instances" => [
       [1.18730158, -0.70909592,  1.21082918, -0.15897608, -0.87693017],
       [-0.3015204 , -0.44457891,  0.67090776,  1.1188499 , -0.87693017],
       [-0.52579254, -0.05989349,  0.40094705,  1.62998029,  1.13982729],
       [ 0.13322252,  0.58198159, -0.94885648,  1.1188499 , -0.87693017],
       [ 0.77441082, -0.68638116, -0.13897436,  0.35215431,  1.13982729],
       [ 0.69102759,  1.49057189, -0.13897436, -0.67010647,  1.13982729],
       [-0.25436574, -0.58819479,  0.13098635, -0.15897608,  1.13982729],
       [ 1.54671206,  2.58088026,  2.0207113 , -1.56458465,  1.13982729],
       [-0.97261165, -0.6292279 ,  0.40094705, -1.56458465, -0.87693017],
       [-0.36190136,  0.14893573,  0.40094705,  0.09658912,  1.13982729]
     ]
    ];
```

and then `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($inputData)`

Comment: This works, but I need to store my input in a variable first because that will come from a database query. What should I do? @Always Sunny

Comment: @RachelWatson my bad no need to add the `[]` between `$inputData`. see edit again

Comment: or pass the `$inputData` directly

Comment: @RachelWatson your `$inputData` had some issue, please have a look the edit again

Comment: Yes, I also figured that out from how you had pasted the data within the text and edited the question. You have done me a great favor! I am obliged